# Does Aviarc support Jasper chart themes?

Tags: jasper-reports, aviarc

I have a Jasper report i want to use in Aviarc and it has a chart theme. I have created it in iReport and it works fine after creating the .jar file. When i try to use it in Aviarc it can't find the theme .jar - i have placed it in both the reports and reports/lib directories.

Does Aviarc support Jasper chart themes and if so how is it implemented?.

Thanks,
Tim